# Why am I getting these errors when including stb_image.h?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to put an include guard around including `stb_image.h` (from the well-known public domain image library).

I have noticed that, unusually, the include guard works inside the `.cpp` file but not inside the header file.

Let me explain:
Inside `texture.h`:

```
//This is something that stb image defines in its own include guard, so I should be able to test for it
#ifndef STBI_INCLUDE_STB_IMAGE_H
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#endif
```

This gives me errors (multiple definitions of everything inside `stb_image.h`), but the same code in `Texture.cpp` does not give me an error.

Also, I'd like to note that this does not work either:

```
#ifndef WHOMST
#define WHOMST
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#endif
```

Comment: `stb_image.h` already has it's own include guard. You don't need to write it yourself.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348798/double-inclusion-and-headers-only-library-stbi-image

Answer (score 5):

From the stb_image.h file itself:

> Do this:
>         #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION    before you include this file in *one* C or C++ file to create the implementation.

You must **not** `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` in header (.h) files.

Only in one C/C++ file to create the implementation (the stuff that has to be unique and done only once.)

The header files can include stb_image.h but must not have this preprocessor macro defined.

Screenshot with added highlight:

[image]

Comment: IOW, `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` is **not** the include guard for `stb_image.h`.